# auto correct misspelled words in a list of lists - python

Tags: python, multithreading, nlp, nltk, text-mining

I have a list of lists containing words/tokens.

```
Eg:- [[u'note', u'subject', u'mussage', u'aar', u'install'],[ u'accomplishment', u'survice', u'hte', u'skinn', u'damaged', u'location', u'shown']
```

Need a python script which auto corrects the misspelled words and provides the results as.

```
Eg:- [[u'note', u'subject', u'message', u'air', u'install'],[ u'accomplishment', u'service', u'the', u'skin', u'damaged', u'location', u'shown']
```

I have around 2 million lists each having more than 5000 words/tokens. How to do a script which completes the job in very short time

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: [Very less](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38202/is-very-less-correct-english) doesn't mean anything, and if you need something to be done in a certain amount of time, you have to be clear. For someone that might be 10 milliseconds, but others might be fine with 10 seconds.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I actually used a traditional 'for loop' for the problem, the execution took more than 48 hours and was still running. Hence have requested for a solution which could run in few hours. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[autocorrect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autocorrect)** lib to accomplish your task.

```
from autocorrect import spell

k = [[u'note', u'subject', u'mussage', u'aar', u'install'],[ u'accomplishment', u'survice', u'hte', u'skinn', u'damaged', u'location', u'shown']]

res = [map(spell, l) for l in k]
print res
```

Result:

```
[[u'note', u'subject', u'message', u'Aar', u'install'], [u'accomplishment', u'service', u'the', u'skin', u'damaged', u'location', u'shown']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works perfectly fine in terms of functionally, but takes too much time. Can you please help me with a script which runs much faster than this.Thanks again

Comment: have to use Speller now. instead of Spell. "from autocorrect import speller"